# How to Use Outer Sdk(API) in our Project

Tags: xcode, api, sdk, barcode

I have barcode sdk(API), i want use it on my project. But dont know how it is?
Please tell me is there any simple way.

Thank you,
Anand

Comment: Which SDK? I can find nothing about an Outer SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all outer SDK comes with help document or online documentation on how to use/integrate it in your code.Which SDK are you talking about by the way...?  most of the time you need to add the **src folder/Static Lib(lib.a file)** and give header and/or lib path in your project setting...

I have used `LineaSDK` for barcode in which you need to add libLineaSDK.a static lib in your project and also you need to add LineaSDK.h file in your project

Comment: you'll find some documentation on how to add it in your xcode project and most probably it will also have some sample app in which the sdk has been added.